# Android: using getname() of XMLPullParser

Tags: android, xml

I'm using a `XmlPullParser` to read a xml file. 
My file has the following line:

```
<Circle>
<Circle time="2015-12-21">
```

And my problem is on the second line, because I'm using `getname()` but it only returns `Circle` instead of returning `Circle time="2015-12-21"`.

My code:

```
URL url = new URL(site);
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser()

while (xpp.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {           
        continue;
    }
        name = xpp.getName();

    if (name.equals("Circle time=\""+getDate()+"\"")) {
       Log.d("Example","Success!!");
    }
}
```

`name` is always `Circle` instead of `Circle time="2015-12-21"`.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

time is an attribute. To retrieve its value you can use
[getAttributeValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)][1]. `getName` returns the name of the current tag.

```
  String name = xpp.getName();
  if ("Circle".equals(name)) {
      String time = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "time");
      // here time contains the content of the attribute
      // you can compare it with getDate();
  }
```

[1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html?hl=es#getAttributeValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: when I do Log.d("Example","time:"+time) inside the if you wrote it returns me that time is null...am I do it wrong?

Comment: well it depends on the structure of your xml. You posted one tag Circle without time and the other with.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was comparing to '"Cube time=\""+getDate()+"\""', to enter in the second tag

Comment: it will give you null for the first tag, but not for the second one.